# Wordpress Custom Fields not displaying the section

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have added a new layout in the Wordpress Custom fields plugin, and after adding it I have added the fields in the corresponding php file too. But for some reason, its printing the code in the browser. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am new to WordPress, so can someone please help me?
Screenshots attached for reference.

PHP file code - https://codeshare.io/GklExO
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I had to add an image tag and then it worked fine.
However, there are other PHP files in the site, where
`<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>` displays the image, but in this particular case I had to write it as

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>"/>
```

Still trying to understand how this works.